# Is it possible to call ant task from a javascript scriptdef task?

Tags: ant

Is it possible to call an ant task that is in the same ant script from a javascript scripdef task?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. In case you meant target, rather than a task, here are examples of both:

```
<target name="test">
    <echo message="In test target" />
</target>

<scriptdef name="demo" language="javascript">
<![CDATA[
    self.project.executeTarget( "test" );

    var task = project.createTask( "echo" );
    task.setMessage( "In demo task" );
    task.perform( );
]]>
</scriptdef>

<demo />
```

When run, yields:

```
test:
     [echo] In test target
     [echo] In demo task
```

It may be useful to refer to the [Ant API](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.4/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.html) and docs for the [`script` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html).

Comment: Is it possible to set properties on the target invoked by project.ExecuteTarget?

Comment: To pass properties to a target, you need to use the antcall task. That applies to both "pure XML" and scripted Ant. So to call a target called "process" with a "pattern" property set do something like: `var task = project.createTask("antcall"); task.setTarget("process"); var param = task.createParam(); param.setName("pattern"); param.setValue(regexp); task.perform();`.